# Python Files Not Deleting After being Zipped

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've created a few functions which all work fine, when they are being outputed as an array, this has no issues and does not throw any error at all. For user ease, I've wanted to pack all these files into a ZIP folder, I've used the zipfile import in python to do this. However, I get an error when it comes to deleting the zip folder and the associated directory. The error I am getting is:
`Application Command raised an exception: PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'sent\\mp_m_freemode_01-task_diff_001_[A-Z]_uni.ytd'`

This is my python code:

```py
for file in glob.glob('sent/*.ytd'):

            discord_prep = discord.File(file)
            uniforms.append(file)

            print("-- File to Send --")
            print(file)
            print("- File to Send Array -")
            print(uniforms)

        with zipfile.ZipFile(name + ".zip", mode="w") as archive:
            print("Making Archieve")

            for filename in uniforms:
                print(filename)
                archive.write(filename)

        archive.close()

        final_zip = discord.File(name + ".zip")

        await discord.asyncio.sleep(1)

        await ctx.send(
            file=final_zip
        )

        os.remove(name + ".zip")

        removing_files = glob.glob('sent/*.ytd')
        dir = os.listdir("sent/")

        if not len(dir) == 0:
            print("Clearing YTDs from Sent Folder")
            for i in removing_files:
                os.remove(i)

            print("All YTDs Removed")
        else:
            print("No YTDs to Clear")

        shutil.rmtree("sent/", ignore_errors=False, onerror=None)
        print("Sent Folder Deleted")
```

I tried and ensured that all my with open methods are closed and they are, but this error only occurs when I run the ZIP instructions, claiming it is being used in another device.

Comment: The error says that some OTHER program has the file open.  Did you check for this?

Comment: @JohnGordon: I've seen that error message also in cases it was my own program. I wouldn't rely on "other" too much. But in many cases, it was the virus scanner

Comment: When I try to delete it manually says its being used by python.exe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to troubleshoot such issues on Windows, use [SysInternals Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer).

Go to the menu Find / Find Handle or DLL... or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>. Then enter the file name or a part of the file name. Don't use wildcards. Process Explorer will then list all processes which access the file.

[image: Example for mscoree]

Comment: I tried this, with both the full name of the file and just the extension, but nothing appeared. I am using PyCharm as my IDE so not sure if that is relevant. Here is a screenshot:

https://gyazo.com/0b0ad0499ecdef38370cba13182babd9

PyCharm: 
https://gyazo.com/c73dfad817302fd5709b0ab490e8674b

Comment: @Welshy1235: the following can happen: virus scanner scans the file. You can't delete it. Until you opened Process Explorer, the virus scanner has finished analyzing the file. Did you run Process Explorer as admin?